# How can I assign a Google Sheet script to only one sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, build-automation

I have this script here, but I want it to only run on ONE specific sheet named "Nes Smart Data" (SheetNo5). Currently it runs on all sheets and puts the data on cells where I don't want them to be. Can you help me correct the code? Thanks a lot!

```
function onEdit(e){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;
  var column = range.getColumn();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var text; 

  if (column==11) { //Replace 2 with the column number of your comments cell//
    var newRange = sheet.getRange(row,column-5); //If the date is in the next column
    var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),'dd.MM.yyyy');
    newRange.setValue(today);
  }
  if (column == 11){
    text = sheet.getRange(row, 23).getValue();
    sheet.getRange(row, 23).setValue(text + e.value+".");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the following variable and things should work as desired -

**Current:**

`var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();`

**Modification proposed:**

`var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Nes Smart Data');`

Let me know if it doesn't!